# Testflight "This build is not available for this platform" - iOS required on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

See title. Client is seeing "This build is not available for this platform (iOS required)." Install button is greyed out.

iPad 2 version 6.1.3

My same model has installed and an iPad 3 has installed.

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling on your device? I had weird things happen today with TestFlight that cleared up later on. This just might be a "Try again" situation.

Comment: Reinstalling fixed it. Post to get answer credit, thanks!

Comment: Thanks quantumpotato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling on your device? I had weird things happen today with TestFlight that cleared up later on. This just might be a "Try again" situation.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem on Testflight's end. Seems like they are unable to recognize your client's device. For now, [fall back to the original way to do it](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/how-to-distribute-ad-hoc-build-with-xcode-4/), or wait for Testflight to fix the issue.